# how to change the name of column family in the hbase table

Tags: hbase

I have a Hbase table with only 1 column family(cf1) having 100 columns under it. I need to change  cf1 to new column family(CF1).

In short i need to modify column family name. I have gone through the following link http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/30959  but of no use.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should copy columns from family to family then delete old column family. If there was a hbase client api for that, it would do the same, i think. Because data written to hbase files contains column family name in it.

Comment: Thanks Halil. May i know how to copy data from 1 column family to another column family?

Comment: I would do it by java api, but if your table is huge, for example bigger than 100gb, i think you can use hbase remote coprocessors to copy data in their region. This way data will not transferred over network to your client.